# Require function does not work in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have a smart contract that uses `require` to validate the parameters inside some functions and I have noticed that geth 1.9.13 and 1.9.14 do not enforce the condition in `require`. I could reproduce the problem with this simple smart contract

```
 pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.0;

 contract NodeContract {
    
    
      // Define the struct with the data of a node
      struct Node {
        // UUID
        bytes32 nodeId;
      }

      uint numberOfNodes = 0;
    
      mapping (uint => Node) nodes;

      constructor() public {
      }

      function publishNewNode(bytes32 nodeId) external returns(uint256)
      {
       
        uint256 nodeIndex = numberOfNodes;
        
        nodes[nodeIndex] = Node({nodeId:nodeId});

        numberOfNodes += 1;

        return (nodeIndex);
       }

    
      function getNodeData(uint256 nodeIndex) external view returns(bytes32  nodeId)
      {
        require(nodeIndex < numberOfNodes, "The nodeIndex supplied is larger than the number of available nodes");

        return (nodes[nodeIndex].nodeId);
      }
    

      function nodesCount () external view returns(uint) {
       return (numberOfNodes);
      }
}
```

If I deploy it on https://remix.ethereum.org/ and I call `getNodeData(0)` then I get the expected error message `Reason provided by the contract: "The nodeIndex supplied is larger than the number of available nodes".`. If I deploy that contract in my private blockchain in geth and call `myContractInstance.getNodeData.call(0);` I get `0x` which means that the whole function executes instead of stopping at the require line. Is there a way to fix this and get the expected behavior?

Comment: There's an open issue on that for at least for one these two versions of geth. Get rid of the error-message (the second parameter in the `require` statement), and you should be fine. I think that this issue also exists **independently** on web3.js in case you're using that in conjunction with your private network (the question doesn't say).

Comment: Note that the issue is specifically for `require` statements which contain an error-message AND called from constant (`pure` or `view`) functions.

Comment: Issue in web3's repo https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3435#issuecomment-631482263, with links to geth's repo issue